# Java HashMap Iterate Each Variable and Return Value

Tags: java, loops, methods, hashmap, return

I have a class with various Booleans and Integers.

```
class Animal  {

    boolean mHappy = false;
    boolean mHungry = false;
    boolean mSleeping = false;
    int mCost = 0;
    int mWeight = 0;


    boolean isEmpty() {
        return !mHappy && !mHungry && !mSleeping && mCost == 0 && mWeight == 0;
    }
}
```

The method boolean isEmpty() will tell me if all the values are empty.

Now, I want to move all my data into HashMaps:

```
class Animal  {

    HashMap<String, Boolean> mBools = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{
        put("mHappy", false);
        put("mHungry", false);
        put("mSleeping", false);
        }
    };

    HashMap<String, Integer> mInts = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
        put("mCost", 0);
        put("mWeight", 0);
        }
    };


    boolean isEmpty() {
        // MY QUESTION: How can I make this function iterate through each HashMap,
        // regardless of size, and check to make sure it's "false" or "0" like this
        // line did when I only was using static booleans and integers?
        return !mHappy && !mHungry && !mSleeping && mCost == 0 && mWeight == 0;
    }
}
```

**My Question is about the "boolean isEmpty()" method, How can I make this function iterate through each HashMap, regardless of size, and check to make sure each value is "false" or "0"?**

Comment: Note that a primitive boolean cannot be 'empty'. The value `false` is just as valid as `true`, and `false` does not mean the value is unused.  If you really want to distinguish "empty" from a valid boolean you must use `Boolean` objects, so the reference can be `null` to indicate "empty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
boolean isEmpty() {
    for (int i : mInts.values()) if (i != 0) return false;
    for (boolean b : mBools.values()) if (b) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Read the [map tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) for more info about iterating through the contents of a map.

Comment: +1, but some alignment and braces would make it easy to read, atleast to me

Answer (score 2):

Call the [`values()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) on each map; you can iterate through the returned `Collection` of values.  Then you can check each value to see if they are `0` or `false` as the case may be.

Keep a `boolean`, initialized to `true`, if everything is "empty" so far.  Set it to `false` if a value isn't `0` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to iterate over the values in your maps:

```
boolean isEmpty {
  for (Integer i : mInts.values()) {
    if (i > 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  for (Boolean b : mBools.values()) {
    if (b) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```